# How to find other AWS Users Canonical Id using Root User credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am having AWS Root User credentials. I have created 5 users through https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users -> Add User. Out of 5 (2 Programmatic User and 3 AWS Management Console access users).

How can I find all 5 user's Canonical Id or Mail Id, through Java API or https End Point using Root User's Credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you **can't do this**. This is because [Canonical user ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html) is the ID for the **entire account**, not individual IAM users:

> An alpha-numeric identifier, such as 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be, that is an obfuscated form of the **AWS account ID**. You can use this **ID to identify an AWS account** when granting cross-account access to buckets and objects using Amazon S3. You can retrieve the canonical user ID for your **AWS account** as either the root user or an IAM user.

To get it for the account, you can use CLI or any equivalent in SDK:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID --output text
```

Comment: in case your user cannot list buckets, you can use existing object (or upload a new one into a bucket) and check its ACL with CLI: `aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket <bucket-name> --key <an object/file key>`